# transformation or GLM approaches for compositional explanatory variables and a fractional outcome

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-transformation, compositional-data

I have a model where the outcome $y \in (0,1)$ is a share variable.

The four explanatory variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are compositional, so they sum to one. They are also all in $(0,1)$.

My goal is to have a model where re-transformation bias is not a problem (which rules out OLS with non-linear transformations of $y$) and that is not overly complicated (I have micronumerosity problem and want some interpretability).

My initial thought was fractional regression or even beta regression, but I am not sure what would be the best way to transform the RHS variables (if at all).

Are there explanatory variable transformations (like the natural log) and/or GLM approaches that are well suited to this problem?

Comment: do you only have the response variable in the  $(0,1)$ interval or do you have a count as in $\frac{y}{n}$?

Comment: I know both the numerator and the denominator counts.